# Sending AJAX call after some PHP condition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP condition

```
if (isset($person->image) && $person->name == 'Sam')
{
  // Javascript logic 
}
```

If this PHP condition matches, I want call an AJAX request and get the data. I want to save this data I get from AJAX call to the database as well.

I don't know what to do, and how to connect this PHP condition with a Javascript AJAX request.

Please guide me.

Comment: You can use 
`if (isset($person->image) && $person->name == 'Sam'){echo "<script> yourfunction(); </script>";}` 
where "yourfunction()" is your AJAX call

Comment: Do you have more information about what exactly you are trying to achieve? There may be a more straightforward way to do what you want. Try to think outside of 'why do I need ajax'? And also consider 'the progression of php and html'. We are here to help, but would like more information to go on.

Comment: The `if` condition is in PHP already, so what's the point of creating JS code to make an AJAX request to get information you already have access to...?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I really don't know, my brain is not capable enough to process your question :(

Comment: @Cowgirl What's the AJAX call you want to make? If all you want is to get some information you can just `echo` it inside the conditional, so you can save one AJAX call and have the information rendered immediately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your PHP condition where you would place the Javascript and echo/print the javascript.

```
<?php
    if (isset($person->image) && $person->name == 'Sam'){
        // Javascript logic
        echo "<script>do.ajax.now('responceToAjax.php')</script>";
    }
?>
```

OR

within your existing script block, use a flag like `doAjax = true` and then call your ajax `if (doAjax == true) { do.ajax.now() }`

now in your PHP page called by your AJAX

```
<?php
    // get the $_POST/$_GET values
    // connect to db and insert stuff
    // return a response if you wish
    echo 'we did it!'
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($person->image) && $person->name == 'Sam'): ?>
<script>
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "ajax-url.php",
  data: {
    personImage: "<?= $person->image ?>",
    personName: "<?= $person->name ?>"
  }
});
</script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Under ajax-url.php You have script which saves this data. But I do not know why You want to do this in this way. You can just save data using this same PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
<?php
if (isset($person->image) && $person->name == 'Sam')
{
?>
// Js code for ajax call
$.ajax({
    type: <type>,
    url: <url>,
    data: <data>,
    beforeSend: function () {
    },
    success: function (response) {
    }
});
<?php
}
?>
```